# docker-compose environment variables are not picked up

Tags: docker-compose

env_file always points to .env by default and it doesn't pickup environment variables from any other file say service.env or .env.service

```
docker-compose -f service-docker-compose.yaml up
```

I tried the following naming conventions within the service definition and it never picks up the definitions from these files

```
env_file: ./service.env
env_file: ./.env.service


docker-compose --version
docker-compose version 1.27.4, build 40524192
```

Answer (score 0):

How are the definitions in that file written?

Here's an example of my docker-compose.yml:

```
services:
  blabla:
    env_file: configuration/env.list
```

Then using KEY=VALUE does it for me.

I used env_file: env.list or env_file: .env in the past. Does that work? You're using **./** before the .env.

Comment: I just tried ./ since it didn't work without them, but none doesn't make a difference

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce your problem. I have created a gist for you: https://gist.github.com/merjn/9b34839d6f339fb3b7b623ba545f52fa

This works for me: https://prnt.sc/yoq463. You might be able to build your application up from what I gave you and wait until you encounter the problem again.

Comment: env_file argument is not taken as an input, we noticed that it only reads from .env file

Comment: Renaming env_file to 'blabla.env' works with my example. Could you perhaps send me your service-docker-compose.yml file?